# Android Google Pay Billing - Response 4 : ITEM_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

I am trying to integrate Google Play Billing.

Here is my onCreate :

```
private final static String     TAG = "MainActivity" ;
private final static String     ITEM_SKU_SUBSCRIBE = "sub_example" ;
private final static String     PREF_FILE = "shared_prefs" ;
private final static String     SUBSCRIBE_KEY = "subscribe" ;

private BillingClient                   billingClient ;

private TextView                        premiumContent ;
private TextView                        subscriptionStatus ;
private Button                          purchaseButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    premiumContent = findViewById(R.id.premium_content) ;
    subscriptionStatus = findViewById(R.id.subscription_status) ;
    purchaseButton = findViewById(R.id.button) ;

    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .setListener(this)
            .build() ;
    billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished ; billing response code == " + billingResult.getResponseCode());
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                Purchase.PurchasesResult queryPurchase = billingClient.queryPurchases(SUBS);
                List<Purchase> queryPurchases = queryPurchase.getPurchasesList();
                if (queryPurchases != null && queryPurchases.size() > 0) {
                    handlePurchases(queryPurchases);
                } else {
                    saveSubscribeValueToPref(false);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "ELSE : " + billingResult.getDebugMessage()) ;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service disconnected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() ;
        }
    });

    if (getSubscribeValueFromPref()) {
        purchaseButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        premiumContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        subscriptionStatus.setText("Subscription Status : Subscribed");
    } else {
        premiumContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        purchaseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        subscriptionStatus.setText("Subscription Status : Not Subscribed");
    }

    purchaseButton.setText("Load products");
    purchaseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            subscribe();
        }
    });
}
```

When I click on the `purchaseButton`, I call `subscribe` function.

Basically it just call a function `initiatePurchase` if `billingClient.isReady()` returns `true`, and initialize `billingClient` in the other case.

Here is my `initiatePurchase` function :

```
private void        initiatePurchase() {
    List<String>                    skuList = new ArrayList<>() ;
    SkuDetailsParams.Builder        params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder() ;

    skuList.add(ITEM_SKU_SUBSCRIBE);
    params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(SUBS);
    BillingResult   billingResult = billingClient.isFeatureSupported(BillingClient.FeatureType.SUBSCRIPTIONS) ;
    Log.i(TAG, "Billing response code == " + billingResult.getResponseCode()) ;
    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Billing response code is OK");
        billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
                new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onSkuDetailsResponse ; billing result response code == " + billingResult.getResponseCode());
                        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Billing response code OK") ;
                            if (skuDetailsList != null) {
                                for (int i = 0 ; i < skuDetailsList.size() ; i++) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Loop INDEX " + i + " ; SkuDetails == " + skuDetailsList.get(i).getTitle()) ;
                                }
                            }
                            if (skuDetailsList != null && skuDetailsList.size() > 0) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "skuDetailsList is not null or empty");
                                BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                                        .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList.get(0))
                                        .build();
                                Log.i(TAG, "Flow Params = " + flowParams.getAccountId() + " | " + flowParams.getSku());
                                BillingResult billingFlowResult = billingClient
                                        .launchBillingFlow(MainActivity.this, flowParams);
                                Log.i(TAG, "billingFlowResult == " + billingFlowResult.getResponseCode() + " | " + billingFlowResult.getDebugMessage()) ;
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Item not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error - " + billingResult.getDebugMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sorry, subscription not supported. Please update Play Store",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

It seems to go to `onSkuDetailsResponse`, with a billing response code OK.

I loop in the `skuDetailsList` and I get `sub_example`, which is my `ITEM_SKU_SUBSCRIBE` (and the one on my Play Store Console) ; so my `skuDetailsList` is not null or empty.

But then, here is my log output :

```
I/MainActivity: Billing response code == 0
    Billing response code is OK
I/MainActivity: onSkuDetailsResponse ; billing result response code == 0
    Billing response code OK
    Loop INDEX 0 ; SkuDetails == Monthly sub (Test Billing)
    skuDetailsList is not null or empty
I/MainActivity: Flow Params = null | sub_example
I/MainActivity: billingFlowResult == 0 | null
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@cb159f0
```

[image: Google Play error]

When I click on the "OK" button, interesting logs appears :

```
W/ProxyBillingActivity: Activity finished with resultCode 0 and billing's responseCode: 4
W/BillingHelper: Couldn't find purchase lists, trying to find single data.
W/BillingHelper: Received a bad purchase data.
    Couldn't find single purchase data as well.
```

I looked up in `BillingClient.class` and I found `int ITEM_UNAVAILABLE = 4;` in the `interface BillingResponseCode`

- I am compiling and launching this app in signed release configuration
- An older version of the app is published in alpha on Google Play (but with the same version code and version name)
- My google play account is in the testers list, it's a @gmail address I created today for this (my other google account was not with a @gmail address - well, did not work either)
- I created this subscription yesterday on the Google Play Console
- My app is published (not in reviewing) since yesterday in alpha.
- I followed this tutorial : https://programtown.com/how-to-make-in-app-purchase-subscription-in-android-using-google-play-billing-library/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the only thing to do was to wait...
It worked this morning.
Count 2 days for your inapp payments to be available on the app.

Comment: Probably deleting Play Store's app date on the device would have helped too.

Answer (score 0):

After adding as a tester, don't forget to accept the invite. the invite URL is at the Google Play console setting test account page. I resolve it by that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).